# can "Every" be used as the Subject of a Sentence?

Tags: grammar, adjectives, determiners

"Every can't be used as a subject since it is a determiner"   is this sentence correct ? Here Every is being used as a subject but we know every is a determiner , how is it possible ?

Comment: You're using the word as a word. Normally you would put it in quotes or italics to make it obvious that it's being used literally. Or precede it with *the word*. (You don't normally need to do both, but I'll do so here to illustrate.) Like this: *The word **every** can't be used as a subject …*

Comment: what if there was no quotes ? would that be still valid ?

Comment: @Saman What exactly do you mean by "valid"?

Comment: @Saman It really doesn't have to be anything specifically. The important part is that the word that's being referred to uniquely (not taking on its normal grammatical role) is set off from the surrounding text in some way. Quotation marks or italics are just a standard convention. You could do any number of different things to make the word stand out. A different size, font face, colour, and so on.

Comment: @JasonBassford So it means a word  which is not Noun can be used as  Noun (i.e Subject) but Its meaning will be different from when it holds its real Grammatical Profile. am I correct ?

Comment: @Saman Exactly so. When a word (or even phrase) itself is referenced, it's used within that reference as a noun, losing whatever grammatical role it would normally have.